# Can two non-nested for loops be condensed into one?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a sample question where we are required to find multiples of 10 between two numbers. Here's the code I've written, and although it works, is there a better way to write this code?

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = keyboard.nextInt();
    int limit = keyboard.nextInt();
    int div = 10;

    for (;div<value;div+=10)
        System.out.print("");

    for (;div<=limit;div+=10)
        System.out.println(div);

    keyboard.close();
```

The first for loop irks me. Any suggestions?

Comment: This loop: `for (;div<value;div+=10) System.out.print("");` does **absolutely nothing** - just so you know!  :)

Comment: Other than increase the value of `div` from `10` to `value` (+/- 10)

Comment: Yeah, i had to increase the value of div to >value.  How else could i do that?

Comment: Umm... wel.... `div = value` is not acceptable?  If you need a multiple of 10 for the starting value of `div`, then you could use `div = value - (value % 10)`

Comment: ... And if you needed the first value of div to be a multiple-of-10 **greater than** value, you could use: `div = value + 10 - (value % 10)`

Comment: @RalphTorello Incorrect, e.g. `value = 30` -> `div = 40` but it should be `30`, and `value = -30` -> `div = -20` but it should be `10`

Comment: Oh yeah, Boundary case... Your right...  Honestly, I have absolutely no idea what he is trying to do... :)  Possibly I shouldn't have posted at all..

Comment: `for (int i = value % 10; i <= limit; i += 10) System.out.println(i);`   **Is it this???**

Comment: @RalphTorello OP is trying to *"find multiples of 10 between two numbers"*, e.g. inputs `value = 27, limit = 43` should print the values `30 40`, with `value` being lower bound, and `limit` being upper bound, both inclusive.

Comment: OK... But then **what** is the **motivation** behind this line?  `for (;div<value;div+=10) System.out.print("");` ???

Answer (score 0):

Using java-8 :

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(value, limit).filter(i -> i % 10 == 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here `value` is the begin index and `limit` is the ending index.

Comment: I use Java 8's `java.util.function` stuff, but I had not used the `System.out::println` - that's neat.  This is a good answer, but you should elucidate what `value` and `limit` are supposed to mean, because in this provided solution, you arbitrarily pick `100` - and I personally cannot tell what how `value` and `limit` are supposed to be used towards producing a result.  I get the multiples of 10 part, but that's all I get.

Comment: I purposely didn't add those values because they are already mentioned in the question. Anyway I've included them now.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.... if they had used `start` and `end` it would have made more sense to me... :)

Comment: For correct output, you need `rangeClosed` and to guard against `value <= 0`, so replace `range(value, limit)` with `rangeClosed(Math.max(10, value), limit)`

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print("")` does nothing, so your first loop can be re-written as:

```
int div = 10;
for (; div < value; div += 10)
    ;
```

The effect of that code is that `div` is the value of `value` rounded up to the nearest multiple of 10. This can be calculated as follows, using `int` math (where division by 10 rounds down):

```
int div = (value + 9) / 10 * 10;
```

The original code will result in a minimum value of `10`, so if `value <= 0` the formula will calculate incorrectly. We can use a ternary conditional operator to account for that:

```
int div = (value <= 10 ? 10 : (value + 9) / 10 * 10);
```

So, the abbreviated version of your code becomes:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int value = keyboard.nextInt();
int limit = keyboard.nextInt();

for (int div = (value <= 10 ? 10 : (value + 9) / 10 * 10); div <= limit; div += 10)
    System.out.println(div);

keyboard.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Explained very simply using only elementary concepts that I've learned in my first month of programming.